# Visible and hittestobject not working

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, visible, hittest

Help me with my code
okay so the problem is that 
the object (text12) is suppose to be visible after 
object (char1) touches object (char2)
but when char1 touches cha2 the text isnt visible even after they touch

```
jah._visible = false;
if(char1.hitTestObject(char2))
{
jah._visible = true; }
```

Comment: forgot about it, added now

Answer (score 1):

If you want your object jah to be `visible` only when char1 touches char2, you can write:

```
if (char1.hitTestObject(char2)) {
    jah._visible = true;
    } else {
    jah._visible = false;
}
```

`bird_mc.hitTest(missile_mc)` returns exactly the same `Boolean` as `texte._visible` (true or false), so you can also write:

```
jah._visible = bird_mc.hitTest(missile_mc);
```